# .ICS file showing 1 hour different in time when save that file

Tags: php, icalendar

I have a program that sends calendar appointments out to users. However these users are in many different time zones. When I create the .ics file, I have create time in GMT timezone, because our server timezone is GMT. They then get sent out to the users, who are scattered across many time zones. They are receiving 1 hour different time when they saving .ics file.

For example i scheduled appointment of 11:30 - 12:30 on 8th Aug it is showing 12:30 - 13:30 on 8th Aug.

My ICS code is here:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//test.com//NONSGML kigkonsult.se iCalcreator 2.18//
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20140806T175536-69581448@test.com
DTSTAMP:20140806T122536Z
DESCRIPTION:Teste
DTSTART:20140808T063000Z
DTEND:20140808T070000Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Test
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Test
TRIGGER:-PT0H15M0S
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This code generated by php code.

Answer (score 2):

Since 11:30 UTC *is* 12:30 British Summer Time, I strongly suspect there is no problem here. The UTC time in your invitation is unambiguous. Your calendar application knows your time zone, and has displayed the meeting in your local (daylight saving) time. People receiving the same invitation in Tokyo and Sydney will see the meeting displayed in their local timezone also.

Comment: Yes, they are receiving invitation in their timezone but time is going +1 hour more. Because i have selected asia/kolkata timezone and 1300 time. I am receiving 1400 time in asia/kolkata timezone outlook.

Answer (score 1):

You define your timezone to be "Europe/London" which uses daylight savings and you define the DTSTART/DTEND in UTC wich has no daylight savings.

Comment: Could you please provide me a sample for `DTSTART` and `DTEND` for daylight saving.

Comment: DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20140819T000000 (without the "Z" at the end)

Comment: But i have to send in different timezone from Europe/London timezone.
May be appointee resides in Asia/Kolkata. So how to make for these type of apointment

Comment: The calendar app of your appointee should take care of this, add the calendar item and calculate the difference between Europe/London and Asia/Kolkata.

Comment: Another approach is, to use UTC datetimes where possible so you'd need to calculate Europe/London->UTC in your app and save the .ics in all UTC